# Count past entries with the same key

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this simplified dataset which has a date and an ID. I'd like to have a new column total with a count of the IDs, but since I'm creating an ML model prediction, I only want to take into account the entries before the actual event.

I'd like to count for each entry only those where Date is smaller. Something like: count all entries where ID is the same and have the date <= the date of the current row, and add a column with that value.

```
ID | Date   | 
1  | 3/4/10 |
1  | 3/6/10 |
1  | 1/2/10 |
2  | 5/5/10 |
2  | 5/6/10 |
```

Result

```
ID | Date   | Total
1  | 3/4/10 | 1
1  | 3/6/10 | 2
1  | 1/2/10 | 0
2  | 5/5/10 | 0
2  | 5/6/10 | 1
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using Pandas, first change the `Date` column to a `datetime` then sort by `ID` then `Date`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,1,2,2], 'Date':['3/4/10','3/6/10','1/2/10','5/5/10','5/6/10']})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.sort_values(['ID','Date'])
```

Now, count the number of `Date`d per `ID`, make a rolling counter with `np.arange` and convert to a `pd.Series`.  Stack the results and voila:

```
df['Total'] = (df
                .groupby('ID')
                .count()['Date']
                .apply(np.arange)
                .apply(pd.Series)
                .stack()  
                .values)  


print(df.sort_index())
        Date  ID  Total
0 2010-03-04   1    1.0
1 2010-03-06   1    2.0
2 2010-01-02   1    0.0
3 2010-05-05   2    0.0
4 2010-05-06   2    1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplified pseudocode which can be implemented with either
`itertools` or `pandas`:

- Group the dataset by `ID` column
- For each group:

  - sort `Date` column
  - `Total` column is the ordinal number of the date.

Answer (score 1):

define a function for checking the date.
use for example.

```
def DateOrderChecker(input):
truncatedInput = input[:n]
trunflip = truncatedInput.reverse()
trunFinal = (trunflip[:v]).reverse()
```

where n is char. at the end of date and v is before. so you would be left with "5/5/10"

now do

```
month, day, year = trunFinal.split("/")
```

and finally make an if string for comparing (year/month/day) < (HeldMonth/HeldDay/Heldyear)

ranking the in importance year>month>day